# Show that $F(U)$ is open

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $F: M \rightarrow N$ be a smooth map between smooth manifolds $M$ and $N$ of the same dimension. Consider $U$ to be an open set in $M$. The lecturer in this video https://youtu.be/eWXnYkVjJ-g around minute 13, says that this implies that $F(U)$ is open, why this is true ?

Comment: As you have stated it, this is not true; consider $M = N = \mathbb{R}$ and the function $f(x) = 1$. If you assume that $f$ is a local diffeomorphism, then this is true.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your comment! Actually, yes in the video  lecture $F$ was a local diffeomorphism. How can we prove that $F(U)$ is open if $F$ is a diffeomorphism ?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @Arctic Char, I'm confused about starting from the assumption that $F:U \rightarrow F(U) \subset M$ is a diffeomorphism ( which implies that $F(U)$ has a smooth structure ) and try to prove that $F(U)$ is open. For me  the statement $F: U \rightarrow F(U)$ include automatically the fact that $F(U)$ is open , so I'm sure I'm missing something!

Comment: @asma Pass to local coordinates and apply the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Is $F$ a diffeomorphism or a local diffeomorphism?

Comment: $F$ is a local diffeomorphism however its restriction $F_{|U}: U \rightarrow F(U)$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Then of course local diffeo implies open by inverse function theorem.